# Error while using ForEach-Object -Parallel with a hashtable

Tags: powershell

To be able to execute queries faster using Invoke-Sqlcmd, I want use a parallel foreach-object.

First, I'm creating a variable which holds all of the views that I need to execute.

```
$DefinedViews = Get-ChildItem -Directory | 
Where-Object { $_.Name -in $DefinedSchemas } | 
ForEach-Object { Get-Item "$($_.FullName)/Views/*" } | 
ForEach-Object {
    @{
        Schema = $_.Directory.Parent.BaseName
        View   = $_.BaseName
    }
}
```

After that, I want to loop in parallel using this code:

```
$DefinedViews |
ForEach-Object -Parallel -Throttlelimit 2 {
    $ViewDetails = $_
    $ViewDetailsArray = $ViewDetails.Schema, $ViewDetails.View        
    try {
        $Query = (Get-Content -Raw ('{0}/Views/{1}.sql' -f $ViewDetailsArray)
        Invoke-Sqlcmd $using:DatabaseDetails -Query $Query 
    }
    catch {
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}
```

This returns in the error:

```
a positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'system.collections.hashtable'.
```

It works fine without the parallel attribute.

Comment: Try `-ThrottleLimit 2 -Parallel { ... }`. The `-Parallel` option takes a scriptblock, which you'd have to place right after the parameter.

Comment: Where is `$DatabaseDetails` defined?

Comment: Databasedetails is defined on top of this script. Didn't include it in this code block. The loop executes a few times, after that the error pops up.

Comment: The issue was related to the order of the parameters. Thanks jeroen

Comment: Before considering parallel threads, I recommend you invest in a proper [PowerShell pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines) first and [avoid wrapping cmdlets in a pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/performance/script-authoring-considerations#avoid-wrapping-cmdlet-pipelines) as this (reconnecting to the database for each query) could be very expensive. `... |Get-Content -Raw ('{0}/Views/{1}.sql' -f $ViewDetails.Schema, $ViewDetails.View) |Invoke-Sqlcmd $DatabaseDetails`

Comment: The [PowerShell Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines) is often misunderstood and underestimated (especially by experienced programmers of languages that don't have a similar feature). Therefore, I have written a PowerShell community blogpost: [Mastering the (steppable) pipeline](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell-community/mastering-the-steppable-pipeline/).